# woocommerce - customise notice error in checkout page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

In my checkout page, when I select county For whom we do not deliver, I have an error message "Unfortunately we do not ship to ID. Please enter an alternative shipping address."
How can I customise this message?

Answer (score 3):

The message itself is not filterable, so the *simplest* way to change it is to basically 'translate' it using the [`gettext`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/gettext/) filter:

```
function wpse_284393_checkout_message( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    if ( $domain !== 'woocommerce' ) {
        return $translated_text;
    }

    if ( $text = 'Unfortunately <strong>we do not ship %s</strong>. Please enter an alternative shipping address.' ) {
        $translated_text = 'New message goes here, %s will be replaced with shipping location.';
    } 

    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse_284393_checkout_message', 10, 3 );
```

***But***, the problem with this solution is that `gettext` is run for *every single line of text* in WordPress. Meaning that every line of text will be checked for the `woocommerce` domain, and then every line of text in WooCommerce will be checked to see if it's the text you want to replace. This can be a [big performance problem](https://pippinsplugins.com/dangers-gettext-filter/).

So, we can try to solve this another way, using the `woocommerce_after_checkout_validation` hook. This hook fires at the end of checkout validation, and is where the error message is generated. Rather than doing a site-wide text replace of the message, we can use this hook to first see if the error message exists, and if so replace it with a new message. Since this will only occur on checkout, it will have much smaller performance implications:

```
function wpse_284393_checkout_message( $data, $errors ) {
    if ( empty( $errors ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $shipping_error = $errors->get_error_message( 'shipping' );

    if ( $shipping_error && $shipping_error === 'Unfortunately <strong>we do not ship %s</strong>. Please enter an alternative shipping address.' ) {
        $errors->remove( 'shipping' );
        $errors->add( 'shipping', sprintf( 'My new error message about shipping %s here.', WC()->countries->shipping_to_prefix() . ' ' . WC()->customer->get_shipping_country() );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'wpse_284393_checkout_message' );
```

By using `sprintf()` and `WC()->countries->shipping_to_prefix() . ' ' . WC()->customer->get_shipping_country()` I was able to set the message up to use `%s` the same way as the original message does.